# Pusher 2 different connections two different channels at the same time

Tags: flutter, websocket, pusher

I have a Flutter app and doing sone messaging staffs.I'm using two different channels for that.First one is presence channel.I'm using this one to keep track online-offline status of all users.And I have another channel to send message from one user to another.When app opened,user subscribes to the presence channel which means that he/she is online but when i subscribe to another channel to send message someone,first channel is disconnecting.I'm using Pusher free plan.